# How to calculate average response time considering business hours?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to calculate average response time for a doctor.

Here's my database schema:

```
mysql> select * from consultation limit 2;
+----+------------------------+
| id | consultation_status_id |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 |                      1 |
|  2 |                      1 |
+----+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from consultation_message limit 2;
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| id | consultation_id | author_id | consultation_message_text | created_at                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|  1 |               1 |         1 | How to treat a fever?     | 2017-07-28 16:01:48       |
|  2 |               1 |         2 | Take Paracetamol          | 2017-07-31 09:03:50       |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to consider only business hours (Mon-Fri 09:00 - 17:00). Given the data above, the result should be:

```
mysql> select id, average_reply_time_in_hours * from user where author_id = 2;
+-----------+-----------------------------+
| author_id | average_reply_time_in_hours |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
|         2 |                           1 |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

because the question was submitted Fri 4pm and the working day ended after an hour and the reply was submitted Mon 9am, so the only hour to include into calculation is the one hour in Friday evening.

Comment: do you have an existing php script for updating the average_reply_time in the user table?

Comment: Very complex, you can take a look here : http://josemarfuregattideabreusilva.blogspot.fr/2012/12/mysql-function-to-calculate-working.html and adapt the function (you don't need holidays I think)

Comment: I don't think it's very complex (but maybe I'm underthinking it). However a dataset comprising 2 rows is hardly representative, is it?

Comment: Do you need to calculate this directly in the query or in your code? If in the query, you should remove the PHP tag. if in your code, what have you tried?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson To be fair, the OP probably doesn't know.

Comment: @Strawberry Probably not. Doesn't really matter either since the OP seem to have gone on holiday. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. This tells you how many working days there are between the two dates:

```
SELECT 5 * (DATEDIFF(LEAST(a.end,LAST_DAY(a.start)),a.start) DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400001234000123440', 7 * WEEKDAY(a.start) + WEEKDAY(a.end) + 1, 1) total 
  FROM 
 (SELECT x.created_at start
     , MIN(y.created_at) end
  FROM consultation_message x
  JOIN consultation_message y
    ON y.consultation_id = x.consultation_id
   AND y.id > x.id
 GROUP 
    BY x.created_at
    ) a;
```